# Scroll bar in Highcharts tooltip

Tags: database, scroll, highcharts, tooltip

I have a lot of data in the tooltip of a highcharts bar chart. Each tooltip data has some 50-60 lines and the complete tooltip is not being able to be displayed in the graph container. In order to view all of it, i want a scroll bar in tooltip. Is it possible?

Here is an example of the code.

[Working jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/o2zmLngr/7/)

Here is the tooltip code. I don't know where to add the scroll bar code.

```
tooltip: {
  useHTML: true,
  pointFormatter: function() {
    var string = '';
    Highcharts.each(toolTip[this.series.data.indexOf(this)], function(p) {
      string += p + '</a><br>'
    })
    return "Incident<br>" + string + "<br />";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add the following CSS:

```
.highcharts-tooltip>span {
   max-height:100px;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

However,there would be a problem regarding the auto-closing of the tooltips. You might have to tweak the events of the highchart.

Comment: As an addition to this post, here you can find live example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/o2zmLngr/10/

Comment: You may also need to add: .highcharts-tooltip {pointer-events: auto !important}

Comment: Is it possible to have custom scrollbar inside it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
.highcharts-tooltip {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
}

.highcharts-tooltip > span {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

set overflow-y and pointer-events can scroll On PC. But on mobile, click tooltip will change.